# In google's dremel, what algorithm that top-k query makes use of?

Tags: algorithm, dremel

Google's Dremel algorithm supports top-k queries. Could somebody tell me what algorithm that top-k query makes use of?

Answer (score 1):

like a Heap ?

A heap can be used to answer query asking for top k elements in a sorted list, in a O(nlogk) time.

see http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=122

Answer (score 0):

I guess you know about the Dremel Paper?

Here is a link: https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/36632.pdf

It says:

> Some Dremel queries,  such as top-k and count-distinct,  return
>   approximate results using known one-pass algorithms (e.g., [4]).

The reference is the following:

> [4]  Z. Bar-Yossef, T. S. Jayram, R. Kumar, D. Sivakumar, and
>   L. Trevisan. Counting Distinct Elements in a Data Stream. In
>   RANDOM, pages 1–10, 2002.

Does this help?